# Text next to brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get the Bootstrap Brand and any accompanying text to be treated together as the brand?

I have tried this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="..." ><img class="img-responsive" src="/brand.png")?>"></a>
            <h3>Ultimate Trade Sizer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

However, I can't get them to be aligned (i.e. side by side). It produces the below effect:

[image: Title and logo should be side-by-side]

Please note that I am using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Your H3 will always be displayed as block by default. Just add CSS styling to treat them as inline.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Wrap the image in a `span`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span><img src="#"/></span>
            Ultimate Trade Sizer
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

`span` defaults to `display: inline`

Comment: Seems to be ok but... text and image are not correctly aligned. There are rules which help in proper positioning .navbar-text class on p tag (bootstrap 3.3.5)

Comment: The text should ideally be inside a suitable tag.. like a heading if it's classed as a heading.. Although beware of your hierarchy. You shouldn't have an H2 or lower tag first on the page, before an H1

Answer (score 20):

The correct solution would be to use `navbar-text` on the `h3` and not to use any additional `div` or `span` elements:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="...">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/brand.png">">
            </a>
            <h3 class="navbar-text">Ultimate Trade Sizer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text for the proper documentation of `navbar-text`.

Comment: If you use p instead of h3, you will get a proper layout. See the description you mentioned.

Comment: `p` seems more reasonable and is also consistent with the bootstrap documentation. Unfortunately I cannot remember why I used `h3` in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this is correct html but I wrapped the image and text in a new div class and floated that left. Also changed the img to the new class with some padding on the right to space it from the text. Seemed to work for me but I am pretty new to bootstrap so it might not be exactly right. Your code would look like this.

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <div class="navbar-brand-name">
                <img src="#"/>
                     Ultimate Trade Sizer
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

add the new css class under the .navbar-brand class

```
.navbar-brand-name > {

  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

}

.navbar-brand-name > img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me. Was the only one where the brand text was properly aligned with the rest of the nav elements. However `padding`seams to stretch the image, `margin` seams to work better:
`margin: -5px 10px;`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `img-responsive` class has `display:block`.  In this case I'm not sure you need that class for the image you are displaying since it is already quite small and not likely to run into issues with needing to be responsive.

Alternatively, you could override `img-responsive` in this instance to `display:inline-block` and also have your `h3` be have `display:inline-block` as well.