# Align image inside a navbar div

Tags: html, css

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <div> <img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
          <h1><span>SUJALA WELLNESS</span> </h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="https://www.kykindia.com" target="_blank">KYK India</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="https://www.kykindia.com/health-benefits/" target="_blank">Health Benefits</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="https://www.kykindia.com/certifications/ " target="_blank">Certifications</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[How do i resize the logo? I want it in same dimensions as navbar. click here to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXd7P.png)

I want the logo to be inside the nav bar and the company's name beside it. How do I align the image and the text. It's ok if the content overlaps the div tag.

Comment: Convert the question to a Plunkr.

Comment: Try creating JSFiddle, because styles are missing. No one can help if he cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: upload your css & js with it. Or make a jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: @skobaljic No, do it primary with the stackoverflow snippet in case of plunkr, jsfiddle or codepen, which you can use secondary: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AbhaySrivastav Do not ask for code in a plunkr or jsfiddle. That will get this question closed. Code **must be within the question itself!**

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code a little bit and tried to do it with flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar__left,
.navbar__right,
.navbar__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar__logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.navbar__title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar__list-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__left">
    <img class="navbar__logo" src="https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/news/2016/08/23/106598324PandawaveNEWS_trans_NvBQzQNjv4Bqeo_i_u9APj8RuoebjoAHt0k9u7HhRJvuo-ZLenGRumA.jpg?imwidth=450" alt="logo">
    <span class="navbar__title">My Company</span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar__right">
    <ul class="navbar__list" role="tablist">
      <li class="navbar__list-item" role="presentation"><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__list-item" role="presentation"><a href="https://www.kykindia.com" target="_blank">KYK India</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__list-item" role="presentation"><a href="https://www.kykindia.com/health-benefits/" target="_blank">Health Benefits</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__list-item" role="presentation"><a href="https://www.kykindia.com/certifications/ " target="_blank">Certifications</a></li>
      <li class="navbar__list-item" role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Since the original code is (highly likely) based on Bootstrap there could possibly appear some conflicts. Still, an upvote for a nice and clean alternative :)

Comment: @McVenco Thanks dude! But true story.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
    <span><img src="images/logo.png"/></span>
    SUJALA WELLNES
</div>
```

If necessary, set a `height: ...px;` on `.navbar-brand img` in your stylesheet. Don't use `<h1>` because `h` tags default to `inline-block` and thus start on a new line

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502040/text-next-to-brand